# Label in asp.net(vb.net) does not display after click button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label which will display if the button submit already enter, how about my label does not display even though have make it visible = true.

This is the asp.net:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblReportIsSaving" runat="server" Visible="False" >Report Is Saving In Progress</asp:Label>

 <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Enter" Width="100px" />
```

This my vb.net, for this matter I would like to display the label first before the 'Save & Update Successful' pop up:

```
Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

        lblReportIsSaving.Visible = True

    Dim intSaveProject, intLastInsertID, intCompanyID As Integer

    strErrMessage = ""

    Try

        lblReportIsSaving.Visible = True

        _strTarget = Page.ResolveClientUrl("test.aspx")
        strPopUpScript = "<script type=""text/javascript"">"
        strPopUpScript = strPopUpScript + "window.location.replace('" & _strTarget & "');"
        strPopUpScript = strPopUpScript + "</script>"

        intSaveProject = fnSaveIntoProject(_strErrMessage)
        lblReportIsSaving.Visible = True

        intLastInsertID = _objCommonData.fnGetLastInsertUserID()

        If intSaveProject = 1 Then
            StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, "Save & Update Successful.")
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "PopupScript", strPopUpScript)
        Else
            StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, "Save & Update Unsuccessful. " & strErrMessage)
        End If

        'btnRegister.Enabled = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        StringBusinessObject.Web.baseClass.fnAlert(Me.Page, ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Can someone help me on this? I just want to make the label visible before the pop up comes out.

Comment: Did you specify the text for the lblReportIsSaving label?

Comment: yes i have...this is the one 'Report Is Saving In Progress'. or we do not need to specify?

Comment: Do you have updatePanel ?

Comment: no i dont have..i dont really know how to use it since i am new to this

Comment: Could you try, remove all the code in btnRegister_Click, then set the lblReportIsSaving.Text to your desired output or text then set the visibility to true. and see what happen.

Comment: when i clicked on enter its like refresh then only the label comes out.

Comment: Can we do something like when client click, then we automatically see that, like using onclientclick?

Comment: @ Elisheva Wasserman can we use the update panel in here?

Comment: UpdatePanel could cause the problem... on the browser, click on "view source" and see if you can find the label 'lblReportIsSaving' after submit

Comment: is it possible that we used onclient click for this?i was thinking maybe when the user click, i just show it straight away.